# Mouse stops when opening a new chrome tab

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

I got a new mouse. It is my first wireless one - yeah, I am aware it's 2017.

The mouse is a Logitech 585. I connected it via Bluetooth and via USB Unity and got the same problem:

whenever something happens like opening a new webpage on my browser, the mouse curser does not move until it is fully done. So, it will stuck for 1 second or something.

This drives me crazy. The device is brand new and I consider to put it back to Amazon. It's the same issue with almost anything, Safari or some other apps which need a bit CPU to open up.

Is this considered normal for wireless mice? I am close to throw my cable mouse back into the game.

Comment: Just started getting this issue myself - it was working fine before a desk move / the xmas break, but now it's started happening. Wonder if a Mac software update / change of position of the unifying receiver might be involved? In any case, same hardware (except MX mouse) and same issue. No satisfactory answer yet. Logitech have never played nicely with Macs sadly - never had these sorts of issues using logitech devices on windows.

Comment: I finally switched to Mighty Mouse 2. Horrible expensive and unergonomic. I am not super happy, but at least, it works without delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is generally no difference if your mouse is wired or wireless, this shouldn't happen. If it happens, it should happen with both wired and wireless mice - that would mean your computer is so slow that it freezes up when you push the CPU a bit.

From your question I assume you didn't have this issue, and only now you got a new mouse and it started doing this. The only reason I can think of is that the mouse uses a proprietary driver that is CPU-intensive and not ran at high enough priority. So when a tab starts loading, it will push the driver process away and the mouse will freeze.

Try checking if the mouse works with Windows' default driver. If not, return the mouse and get another one that does.

Comment: No idea why, but this site removed line breaks from my answer. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have a Mac and this was not the "exact" answer. But it turned out Logitechs additional software causes this delay. I uninstalled it, missing a few features now, but it works like it should. Without you telling me about CPU freeze I would not have thought about it.

Comment: @Christian, having a mac does not inherently mean your CPU is fast. They use the same CPUs as other computers, and they can be just as slow.

Comment: I guess a 2014 MacBook should be able to handle at least wireless mouse. I checked, and it turned out wireless is always having some lag. I just go back to cable now, as I am still not satisfied.